# convert datatype varchar to in magento collection

Tags: magento-1.9, database, collection

i have magento collection

```
Mage::getResourceModel('customizebundles/customizebundles_collection')
                            ->distinct(true)->addFieldToSelect('validity')
                            ->setOrder('validity', 'asc');
```

how can i convert `validity` column `varchar` to `unsigned` like

```
SELECT DISTINCT validity FROM customize_bundles AS main_table order by cast(validity as unsigned)
```

Comment: try `setOrder(new Zend_Db_Expr(cast(validity as unsigned)'), 'asc')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Mage::getResourceModel('customizebundles/customizebundles_collection')
      ->distinct(true)->addFieldToSelect('validity')
      ->setOrder(new Zend_Db_Expr('cast(validity as unsigned)'), 'asc');
```

using `Zend_Db_Expr` will get you the solution.

Answer (score 4):

you can set `cast` as mention @RT

```
$collection->setOrder(new Zend_Db_Expr("cast(validity as unsigned)"), 'asc')
```

**or**

```
 $collection->select()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr("CAST(validity AS unsigned )",'asc'));
```